# Is there any way to get notified about Patient Location Changes using EPIC Vendor Services?

Tags: hl7-fhir, epic, dstu2-fhir, smart-on-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I am building a EPIC Marketplace App (Backend Systems). I want to sync Patient Location within our Database at real-time. But don't know how?.

After reviewing the Documentation there is no any way e.g Webhooks or triggers/Events which I can bind and get real time Patient Location update.

Is there any way to achieve above. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Epic (and practically all common EHRs) doesn't support webhooks. Your best bet for getting real-time notifications of events would be through an HL7v2 interface. For your particular case, an ADT HL7 interface could work well, as you could get A02 messages for transfers or A09/A10 messages for temporary location changes.

Comment: How can I integrate ADT HL7 messaging within my NodeJS app using EPIC fhir?

Comment: HL7v2 messages are typically transmitted over TCP/IP connections and are not something easily handled through a Node app. There are sometimes options for HL7 over HTTPS, but this is not widely supported or available. You should review online documentation about HL7v2 and explore potential options like HAPI's HL7 over HTTP initiative (https://hapifhir.github.io/hapi-hl7v2/hapi-hl7overhttp/index.html).

Your second question seems to be asking for an opinion, but Stack Overflow isn't for opinion-based Q&A.